# How to generate an differente ID for a task on airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to call a function with the `@task` annotation `N` times but I cannot define the `task_id` using this decorator, if I try to call it more than once it says:

> airflow.exceptions.DuplicateTaskIdFound: Task id 'my_task_group.make_request__1' has already been added to the DAG

```
@task
def make_request(params):
    return true

def my_first_function():
    # do stuff
    return make_request(params)

def my_second_function():
    # do stuff
    return make_request(params)

for i in range(0, 10)
    first = my_first_function()  # this will call "make_request"
    second = my_second_function()  # this will also call "make_request"

    first >> second
```

How can I "rename" the `task_id` dinamically on a `@task` annotation?

Comment: Hey Rafa I was wondering if you did find my answer below useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `@task` allows to dynamically generate `task_id` by calling the decorated function. The [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.2/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python._PythonDecoratedOperator._get_unique_task_id) of `_get_unique_task_id` states:

> Generate unique task id given a DAG (or if run in a DAG context) Ids are generated by appending a unique number to the end of the original
> task id.
>
> Example:
> task_id
> task_id__1
> task_id__2
> ...
> task_id__20

With this feature there is no need to dynamically "rename" the tasks. In your code sample, you should decorate the functions that are being call in the loop. Here is a working running version 2.0.1 example:

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
}

@dag(default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(1), catchup=False, tags=['example'])
def task_decorator_example():

    def make_request(params):
        print(f"Params: {params}")

    def _print_task_id():
        context = get_current_context()
        print(f"Result: {context['ti'].task_id}")

    @task
    def my_first_function():
        _print_task_id()
        context = get_current_context()
        return make_request(context['params'])

    @task
    def my_second_function():
        _print_task_id()
        params = {'foo': 'bar'}
        return make_request(params)

    for i in range(0, 3):
        first = my_first_function()  # this will call "make_request"
        second = my_second_function()  # this will also call "make_request"

        first >> second


example_decorated_dag = task_decorator_example()
```

Which creates this graph view:

[image: graph_view]

Each task will print it `task_id` and `params`, the output of the combined logs is like this:

```
- my_first_function
{logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Result: my_first_function
{logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Params: {}
- my_second_function
{logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Result: my_second_function
{logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Params: {'foo': 'bar'}
- my_first_function__1
{logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Result: my_first_function__1
{logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Params: {}
- my_second_function__1
{logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Result: my_second_function__1
{logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Params: {'foo': 'bar'}
- my_first_function__2
{logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Result: my_first_function__2
{logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Params: {}
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: Nice, can I add a specific "id" to the task? my tasks have the same name but different parameters, can I do something like `my_first_function__BR`, `my_first_function__USA` ?

Comment: @RafaAcioly When using this feature you can't do that since the `task_id` gets generated following the logic in `_get_unique_task_id` method.   You could achieve dynamic task_id definition by avoiding the `@task` decorator and simply definining `task_id` argument of your operators, like `task_id=f"my_first_function_{country_name_var}"`

Comment: Actually, it seems to be possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73318279/3659405